# DoubleClick on DataGridView to get more informations

Tags: c#, datagridview

Does anybody know how to make, when you double click on a cell in DataGridView a messagebox appears with more information. So for example i want my DataGridView to only display name and surname but when you Double Click it a messagebox appears with more information like age, heght...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Code the `CellDoubleClick` event of the DGV! It has the Row- and ColumnIndices of the clicked Cell.

Answer (score 0):

First you are going to need to subscribe to the 'CellDoubleClick' event like so:

```
yourDataGridView.CellDoubleClick += yourDataGridView_CellDoubleClick();
```

This will cause you program to start listening for the double click.  In the same class, you have to define the behavior that you want when the DataGridView is double clicked.  The DataGridViewCellEventArgs parameter has values for the current row (e.RowIndex) and the current column (e.ColumnIndex).  Here is an example using one of my DataGridViews:

```
private void dgvContacts_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        //Make sure that the user double clicked a cell in the main body of the grid.
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0) {
            //Get the current row item.
            Contact currentContact = (Contact)dgvContacts.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
            //Do whatever you want with the data in that row.
            string name = currentContact.Name;
            string phoneNum = currentContact.Phone;
            string email = currentContact.Email;
            MessageBox.Show("Name: " + name + Environment.NewLine +
                "Phone number: " + phoneNum + Environment.NewLine +
                "Email: " + email);
        }//if
    }//dgvContacts_CellDoubleClick
```